# ViewdidLoad is called again when moving to next screen on button click

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I know that viewDidLoad is called when the new screen is loaded.
Let's suppose i have 2 screens : Screen 1(main screen) and Screen 2.
When the app starts viewDidLoad of Screen 1 is called.That is right.
The problem i am facing is that viewdidload of Screen 1 is called again when i press the button to move to the Screen 2.
After that viewDidLoad of Screen 2 is called.

Why viewDidLoad of screen 1 is called again on pressing button?

P.S i know that there are no memory issues as i have been developing apps already.This issue is not there in previous apps as i run them now but every new app i create have this issue.
Moreover i am using storyboard and Xcode 5.
And i have tried both push and modal for moving to next screen.

Comment: Have you logged the instance it's called on? Have you put a breakpoint and looked at the stack trace?

Comment: Yes i have put the break point....And still it does that

Comment: But where is it called from?

Comment: from the button click method when i use "performseguewithidentifier.." from there it goes to viewDidLoad of itself and then to next screen

Comment: Why are you using Xcode 5? Xcode 7 just came out. Don't use outdated tools.

Comment: Setting a break point allows you to see the stack at the time a given line executes. It does not stop a line from executing.

Comment: Show the code you have for the button press and prepareForSegue

Comment: In my button method or function i am only moving to next screen,nothing else.i am using [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
As i am sending no data to next screen so not using prepareForSegue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured a stupid mistake.

Actually during the creation of second view Controller it some how(accidentally) became the child of 1st View Controller instead of UIViewController. That's why when i clicked the button to move to the next view.It goes to the viewDidLoad of 2nd view Controller where the method [super viewDidLoad] was called which invoked the viewDidLoad method on 1st screen again.

It is a very stupid mistake.But just sharing it so that it may help some one else.